# Change CSS for dateRangeInput

Tags: css, r, shiny

Given a Shiny app with a dateRangeInput widget, how does one use background color using CSS to modify the separator value (defaults as "to") between the two dates?  The darkly theme overrides the background color to white and white text when combined with the "useShinydashboard()" function:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(

useShinydashboard(),
  
  tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "pi_style.css")
  ),
 
  # Open navbar page and customize the theme
  navbarPage(
    theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
  ),

# Date Input
################################################################################ 
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(

    
    # Date selector
    dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"), 
                   start = "2023-01-01", end = "2023-12-31"),
 
    ) # Close mainPanel
  ) # Close sidebar
) # Close fluidPage


server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And I tried adding this into my custom CSS file (pi_style), based on inspection of the HTML in the app:

```
.input-group-text {
  color: red; background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not self-executable without errors. Also, if this question is still relevant, could you clarify the problem and why the given answer does not address it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out after some CSS sleuthing and added this to my pi_style.css file:

```
/* Controls background color of the dateRangeInput "to" box */
.input-group-addon.input-group-prepend.input-group-append {
  background-color: #464545;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.input-group-text { color: red !important; background-color: red !important; }`